# how to highlight active tab using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How i can highlight a tab that are currently active??? 
 This is my html code.

```
   <a href="#tab1"></a>
   <a href="#tab2"></a>  
   <a href="#tab3"></a> 
   <a href="#tab4"></a>
```

And this is my jquery code that i'm currently using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".tabs").not(":first").hide();

        $(".tab .control a").click(function(){
            storage = $(this).attr("href");
            $(".tabs").hide();
            $(storage).show();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Add some class to your tabs. Then create CSS class that will be added on clicked element.

HTML:

```
<a href="#tab1" class="tab">Tab 1</a>
<a href="#tab2" class="tab">Tab 2</a>
```

CSS:

```
.tab.active {
    background: gray;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.tab').on('click', function() {
    //    Remove .active class from all .tab class elements
    $('.tab').removeClass('active');
    //    Add .active class to currently clicked element
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/cr29y1tc/23/

Comment: Thank you @Roland Ruul appreciate your help god bless.